# df.plot.scatter how can I change the size of the second yaxis?

Tags: python, plot, scatter

here is my python code:

```
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,10))
ax1.tick_params(axis='both', labelsize=18)
test.plot.scatter(x='USFM Durchfluß korrigiert', y='Ausgangsdruck', c='Dichte', ax = ax1, colormap="viridis")
ax1.set_xlabel('Durchfluss [m^3/h]', fontsize=18)
ax1.set_ylabel('Ausgangsdruck [bar]', fontsize=18)
```

*I want to have "Dichte" in the same size as the other axis:*
[image: I want to have "Dichte" in the same size as the other axis]

Comment: Same scale or length of the axis (to make it square) ?

Comment: just the size of the label and the ticks should be the same as for the other axis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to set the general font size of `matplotlib.pyplot` and the font size of the ticks equal with this:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.rc('font',  size=10)  
mpl.rc('xtick', labelsize=10)
mpl.rc('ytick', labelsize=10)
```